# What could be the lambda expression equivalent of the code

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this piece of code and wondering what could be the lambda expression of the same. I tried, in fact, went through the advanced tutorials of the same, still could not figure out the lambda expression of the following code starting from the commented line.

```
IDictionary<string, GitItem> mappedPathToGitItems = new Dictionary<string, GitItem>();

mappedPathToGitItems = clientWrapper.GetFilePathToGitItems(
        gitLatestCommit, versionDescriptor, mappedPath, maxBatchSize);

List<string> filepaths = new List<string>();

// Lambda expression starts from here
// filepaths = {Lambda expression of the below code.}
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, GitItem> entry in mappedPathToGitItems)
{
    string item = entry.Key;
    GitItem gitItem = entry.Value;

    if(gitItem != null)
    {
        filepaths.Add(item);
    }
}
// Ends here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> filepaths = mappedPathToGitItems
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null)
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "lambda expression equivalent" I assume you mean via LINQ:

```
List<string> filepaths = mappedPathToGitItems.Where(item => item.Value != null)
                                             .Select(item => item.Key)
                                             .ToList();
```